# Cider: Evaluate the form preceding point in the REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl, cider

In nREPL, the user could simply C-x C-e to evaluate the preceding form in the running REPL.

However, in Cider, it seems there is only a way to evaluate the form in the echo area or a popup buffer.

Is this really the case?

Please someone correct me, because this is a useful feature to lose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using nREPL and by default evals to echo area.

If you want to send the C-x C-e output to the running repl you can use both solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103177/nrepl-el-how-to-eval-clojure-buffer-form-to-nrepl-buffer-instead-of-echo-area) which are working quite fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm cider's maintainer and I can assure you <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>'s behaviour hasn't changed in quite some time. I'm also absolutely certain nothing was changed when I renamed nrepl.el to cider some time ago. I'm OK with implementing such feature if you need it, though. Just open a ticket on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

`C-c M-e` which is bound to `cider-eval-last-sexp-to-repl` will get the job done. My cider version is 0.16.0.